# Removing unnecessary lines form tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have two cells in my tableview, each with a text field. Following these two cells are many addition lines even though there are no cells to follow. How do I remove these lines to create a cleaner look.

Side Note: 
The reason I didn't use static cells created through the storyboard is because the situation requires to create the cells through code.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And this is for Objective-C

```
tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Swift 3

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove the extra shown empty cells just set `tableFooterView` to an empty view

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```